# Quickly capture location

Tags: org-mode

I always have file called `~/notes.org` open in my emacs. It's my "notepad".

As a developer, I visit hundreds of files every day. Sometimes, I will be inside a file, looking at a method definition

```
module Email
  class SendAlertsWorker < ApplicationWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    sidekiq_options unique: :until_executed

    def perform
```

When I'm on line 7, for example, is there some way I can tell emacs to
insert/append a link to
`file:/whatever/file/I/was/browsing::def perform`

in to my `~/notes.org`

That way, if I have to revisit that particular file location later in the week, I have a convenient link to it in my org file.

Comment: See the manual for [`org-capture`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html).

Comment: These answers use another package which requires it's own configuration and workflow. I think something that simply puts it on the kill-ring or a special buffer would be ideal and stand-alone.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `(org-store-link)` (perhaps bound to `[C-l]`) on the line you wish to save, then call a capture template with `(org-capture)` (perhaps bound to [C-c c]), where the capture template you select uses "%a" to insert the link in the appropriate spot in the todo item in your notes file.

Use something like this for your capture template:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      (quote (
              ("t" "todo" entry (file (lambda () (expand-file-name "~/notes.org")))
               "* TODO [#C] %?\n%a\n")
              )))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use library [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can easily create an Org-mode link that jumps to a bookmark, which destination can be in an Org file (the same or another) or anything else (Info, Dired, any file, an image, etc.)

From section [*Org Mode Links that Jump To Bookmarks*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#OrgModeLinksThatJumpToBookmarks) in the Bookmark+ doc:

> You can also easily define Org-mode links that jump to bookmarks.
>   These links are persistent.  Again, the bookmark linked can be of
>   any type.
>
> You can use the standard Org command `org-store-link` (**`C-c l`**) in
>   buffer `*Bookmark List*` to store a link to the bookmark at point.
>   (This is also item **Store Org Link** in the `mouse-3` popup menu.)
>
> Outside buffer `*Bookmark List*` you can use command
>   **`bmkp-store-org-link`** to store a link to any bookmark.  You are
>   prompted for the bookmark name.  You can even enter the name of a
>   bookmark that does not yet exist.  (This is also item **Store Org Link To...** on menu **Bookmarks**.)
>
> If you use a numeric prefix arg with either command then the
>   bookmark link stored will be for jumping to the bookmark in the
>   same window.  Without a numeric prefix arg, the link will use
>   another window.  (Org mode defines other behaviors for non-numeric
>   prefix args, such as `C-u C-u`.)
>
> As usual, to insert a bookmark link, you use command
>   `org-insert-link`.  Enter the name of the target bookmark at the
>   prompt.  In Org mode you can use the usual Org key bindings to
>   follow the link.  In any mode you can use standard Org command
>   `org-open-at-point-global` (not bound to a key by default).